# MS Access How Do I Get A Count of All Combinations of A 4 Digit Sequence Using Query or VBA

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm trying to use a query to get a count of all possible combinations of 4 digit numbers in a single row in a table? 
I have used a query for 3 digit sequence that worked great. The SQL was like so

```sql
SELECT
    [parent].Results
  , COUNT([parent].Results) AS [Total Results]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Results FROM [Pick 3]
    ) parent
  , [Pick 3] child
WHERE
       child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1)
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1)
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1)
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1)
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1)
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1)
GROUP BY
    parent.Results
```

I tried to use this method with a 4 Digit sequence this is what I came up with.

```sql
SELECT
    [parent].Results
  , COUNT([parent].Results) AS [Total Results]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Results FROM [Pick 4]
    ) parent
  , [Pick 4] child
WHERE
       child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 1234
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 1243
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 1324
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid (parent.Results, 2, 1) 1342
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 1423
    OR child.Results = LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) 1432
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid (parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 2134
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 2143
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 2314
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 2341
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 2413
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 2431
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid (parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 3124
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) 3142
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) 3214
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 3241
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) 3412
    OR child.Results = Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 3421
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 4123
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) 4132
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) 4213
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 4231
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) 4312
    OR child.Results = RIGHT(parent.Results, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 3, 1) & Mid(parent.Results, 2, 1) & LEFT(parent.Results, 1) 4321
GROUP BY
    parent.Results
;
```

This is close but something is wrong I'm not getting all combinations of every 4 digit number in table.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Provide sample-data and expected result (as text).

Comment: [Pick 5] will get funny ,( You should use a VBA-Function to check if`child.Results`is a permutation of`parent.Results`. Just loop through`Split(CStr(child.Results),vbnullstring)`and check if it is in`parent.Results`. If yes remove digit from`parent.Results` and go on. Result is true if you found all in`Split(CStr(child.Results),vbnullstring)` and nothing is left in `parent.Results`. I think a RegEx would do that too (but don't ask me howto).

Answer (score 0):

The SQL DISTINCT keyword will show you each unique entry on one line.
The group by will allow the count to show you how many of them there are.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Res, COUNT(Res) as Hits
FROM ResultsTable
GROUP BY Res
```

does this do what you need?